How to send a message from one contract to another using an interface in Solidity?
Context:
I am developing a smart contract system using Solidity that involves two contracts:
HashedTimeLockEther (Main contract)
Messenger (Interface contract)
Objective:
I want the HashedTimeLockEther contract to notify the Messenger contract when a certain function (like create) is called.

Is the Messenger only an Interface or is there a contract implementation of the same too ?

it has smart contract as well

Okay, and you can basically edit the code of both the contracts (HashedTimeLockEther and Messenger), I mean you're the one who is deploying them. Right?

No, Interface of messenger can implement anyone and pass to create function as argument

Okay, so you can't edit anything in the code of Messenger contract, it's already deployed?

I just can redploy it and continue testing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you can edit both the contracts (Messenger as well as HashedTimeLockEther), then in the Messenger contract:

Define a boolean variable (say isCreateFunctionCalled).
And, define a function (say createFunctionCalled()) that would change the  value of isCreateFunctionCalled to true. Also, you can add a revert condition in order to make this function only callable by the HashedTimeLockEther contract.

Here' the minimal implementation of the same:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Messenger {

    error Messenger__NotHashedTimeLockEther();

    bool public isCreateFunctionCalled;
    address immutable hashedTimeLockEtherAddress;

    constructor(address _hashedTimeLockEtherAddress) {
        hashedTimeLockEtherAddress = _hashedTimeLockEtherAddress;
    }

    function createFunctionCalled() external {
        if (msg.sender != hashedTimeLockEtherAddress) {
            revert Messenger__NotHashedTimeLockEther();
        }
        isCreateFunctionCalled = true;
    }

    // Rest of the code
}

interface IMessenger {
    function isCreateFunctionCalled() external view returns (bool);
    function createFunctionCalled() external;

    // Rest of the code
}

contract HashedTimeLockEther {

    function create(address messengerAddress) external {
        IMessenger(messengerAddress).createFunctionCalled();
        
        // Rest of the body of the create() function
    }

    // Rest of the code
}


after changes i cant deploy contract the tranasaction fails

@Nerses Asaturyan, Deployment of which contract is failing?

both started to fail

Can you provide the code that you’re deploying by creating a gist ?

yeah sure.here it is.    https://gist.github.com/nerses-asaturyan/2510f9c233d7a0739a822d72678dc815

I'm able to deploy your contracts though. Can you please elaborate the exact problem that you're facing?

i need Messenger contract to get data when someone call create function HashedTimeLock

Yes, I got that. But, where are you facing the error, as you said that you're unable to deploy the contracts?

i already succeded to deploy it with remix

Okay, so where exactly are you facing the error?
